# http://localhost:8895 is returning This page isn’t working even if everything seems ok

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastify

I am working with MacOs. This is my fastify code

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

fastify.get('/ping', (req, reply) => {
     reply.send({
        pong: "pong"
    })
})

const start = () => {
    try {
        fastify.listen({ port: 8895 })
    } catch (e) {
        fastify.log.error(e)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

start()
```

It is running inside docker container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8895:8895"
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
COPY *.json ./
COPY *.js ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This is the command I run to work:

> docker-compose down && docker-compose up --build

Everything is working inside the container. I can make also curl inside the container and fastify returns 200. But from my host, requesting `http://localhost:8895`, I am getting:

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `host` option on the `listen`:

- Ref: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#listentextresolver

```js
const start = () => {
    try {
        fastify.listen({ host: '0.0.0.0', port: 8895 })
    } catch (e) {
        fastify.log.error(e)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
```

This is a "security by default" option compared to expressjs.